# Issue deploying app to Heroku from cloud 9

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, heroku, cloud9-ide

I have an app on cloud 9 IDE, it works perfectly on cloud 9 when I run `nodemon server.js` but when I deploy it to Heroku it gives an application error.

**How I am deploying it to git:**

1. Login into Heroku and create an app online
2. Then in cloud 9 terminal I type `heroku login` and then type in my details
3. Then I type `git init`
4. Then `heroku git:remote -a agile-stream-37163`
5. Then `git add .`
6. Then `git commit -am "initial commit"`
7. Then `git push heroku master`

It deploys successfully but when I actually go to the app url it comes up with application error. **I think I am deploying it wrong**, I don't have much experience with git.

Heres an image from my cloud 9 terminal:

[image]

Can anyone please tell me how I can fix this.

Comment: Are all of your node modules installed on your server? Try running `npm install` there. Also would help if you pasted in the error you're seeing here.

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but I had this application error and it was due to the fact that I did not have the start script listed in my package.json file. Doing so solved this issue for me and the app booted fine.